# Where to ask "subjective and argumentative" questions on programming?

Tags: discussion, subjective

Recently [one of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610110/) was "closed as subjective and argumentative".

I wonder, where would you recommend to ask such questions?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but your question itself belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com :-)

Comment: I'm working on a stackoverflowoverflow which will accept the poor, abused, closed questions of SO.  It's still a week or two out, though, so please be patient.

Comment: Can't wait for that... let us know when it's ready!

Comment: @Polly: Only a week or two?  So you're two thirds done?

Comment: @Pollyanna - didn't you mean six to eight weeks?

Comment: To anyone who comes by in the future and is interested in @AdamDavis's comment: that experiment [failed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46551/stackoverflowoverflow-to-be-or-not-to-be).

Answer (score 3):

Well, a few years ago I would have said USENET! Pretty that's what powered its underlying infrastructure...

Comment: What powered its underlying architecture, argument and discord?  I'd buy that.

Comment: I still say it.

Comment: Did you mean "Pretty" or "Pity"?

Comment: Why a few years ago and not now? (coming from a guy who hasn't been on Usenet in 10 years)

Answer (score 2):

IRC.

Comment: Which IRC channel and server do you recommend?

Comment: efnet#politics @ear

Comment: hah. @the cat. Might I suggest running into #linux on freenode :p

Answer (score 1):

There is a programming forum at xkcd.com that I visit from time to time, along with a complimentary "flamewars" board for the obvious ones.. I haven't really needed a forum much since I joined SO though..

Comment: +1 for *"I haven't really needed a forum much since I joined SO though"*

Comment: @polly well it's true. The only times I go to a forum is when I want an open ended discussion to help me figure out a design. Wait no, I just phrase it in the form of an answerable question and ask it on SO. nevermind.

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends on how subjective or argumentative your question is.

If you want to start a so-called flame war, anywhere but here. I don't care whether you prefer vi or emacs or eclipse. Or Linux/Windows or whatever. I have never had time for "what's the best programming language" debates. Such arguments are best left to people who don't have code to write for deadlines.

However, your question was actually on the semantics of a programming language itself and which works best. As such, it *is* about programming, i.e. programming language design and that in itself is valid. It currently has 3 votes to re-open, one from me. I've no idea why it was closed in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I usually refer such questions to [Ask Slashdot](http://ask.slashdot.org) or [reddit's programming forum](http://reddit.com/r/programming).

For Perl-specific discussions, there are [many mailing lists](http://lists.perl.org) dedicated to various components, and [Perl Monks](http://perlmonks.org) rules them all.

Answer (score 1):

(I'll skip the sphiel on why you should never leave stackoverflow :)

I've cruised a lot of other sites before coming to stackoverflow. They're forums, so subjective and argumentative stuff is par for the course. here's the top 3:

[daniweb.com](http://www.daniweb.com/): , broad topics, not just programming and web dev, but many other computer issues. Worth checking out. Daniweb and dev shed are both very broad computer sites, taking questions on software design, hardware, web development, etc.

[dreamincode.net](http://www.dreamincode.net/): programming and web dev help, large site.

[devshed.com](http://forums.devshed.com/) little smaller than the others, been around for awhile.

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo Answers?

SO is for questions that can *be answered*, unfortunately that can't.