# Where, if anywhere on Stack Exchange, should I ask software engineering questions that are subjective?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where to ask “subjective and argumentative” questions on programming?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46389/where-to-ask-subjective-and-argumentative-questions-on-programming)

For example, questions of the following type:

"What are your favorite bash command line tricks?"

"What's are the most important lines to include in your .bashrc file?"

"What are your favorite tricks for working with git?"

I find questions like these very useful for optimizing my workflow, especially when I'm not even aware such an optimization exists, so I wouldn't even know to ask the appropriate question in the first place.

However, these questions are not welcome on Stack Overflow, which imposes strict requirements that questions have a clear answer and be directly related to software engineering. Where then is my best source of such democratically determined best practices?

You can of course google for answers, but this often leads to just a long list of some individual person's favorite tricks, which is often incomplete and doesn't have the backing of a voting system to force the truly most important tricks to rise to the top.

Comment: How is "favorite bash commands" a software engineering question?

Comment: @Shog9, It's very useful in software engineering. It's not exclusive to software engineering, but the best software engineers tend to be extremely proficient.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for these sort of questions is https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ . But, I would take a look at the questions first that are currently being asked, and see if your questions will fit. I'm not quite sure if they would like the example questions that you have posted, but in general, the questions about programming flow, life as a programmer, etc are better suited on Programmers.SE than on SO.

Comment: Also take a look at the [Programmers FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq) and the guidelines laid out in [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

Comment: Programmers.SE is *not* the best bet to ask the example questions. A question merely being subjective doesn't make Programmers.SE the default choice. These are soft questions that don't have a home anywhere on Stack Exchange. See also [Real Questions Have Answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)

Comment: @MarkTrapp: Sorry, I should have made that clearer. I've edited my answer to be more appropriate.