# Closed as "cannot be reasonably answered", I can provide a good answer. What are my options?

Tags: support, reopen-closed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My question is closed due to being “subjective” and “rant” , what are my options?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100661/my-question-is-closed-due-to-being-subjective-and-rant-what-are-my-options)

This question:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/6845636/369489

is closed because:

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is
>   ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot
>   be reasonably answered in its current form.

I think I have actually found the solution and somehow the cause. The relation between the question and my findings are pretty easy to explain. They can be judged, measured and asserted to a good measure objectively and there is very little ambiguity in them.

I think the question should be reopened as I can surely provide a (possibly correct) answer to the question in its current form. What are my options?

Comment: Uh, improve the original question? The people voted to close it for one or more of the listed reasons. If you fix that problem, you can then get it re-opened.

Comment: I've cast the first reopen vote, you need 4 more.

Comment: @Lance Thanks for your support (I suppose ;-) )

Comment: @Cody I think I *can* improve the original question in the light of my recent findings yet doing so would violate my point. My point being the question *can* and *would* be answered in it's original form if hadn't been closed shortly.

Comment: Feel free to answer it now!

Comment: Question seems to be open again now, go ahead and answer

Comment: +1 to Lance because of telling what is required to reopen a closed question (reopen votes).

Comment: @jinguy, MarkJ How do I show my appreciation for your supportive votes?

Comment: [This sounds familiar...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100661/162705)

Comment: @Chris Yeah, Hi Chris

Comment: Wow I read that "Question". Perhaps I can explain the hoopla. It reads like this to me: "I'm talking about PhpStorm's autocompletion. It isn't working well. It sucks. Is this normal?" I don't care if you do take out all the other words, that is a terrible question. Yes, one answer is "Did you delete the cache and re-index everything?" But notice that's a question too. This problem is totally localized to you. Yes it happens to others, but the only useful suggestion for this kind of thing is asking something like "How does one know when the ide's [phpstorm] index is bad and how can one fix it?"

Answer (score 11):

That post could have been closed as either "not a real question" or "not constructive".

> I think the question should be reopened as I can surely provide a (possibly correct) answer to the question in its current form.

You asked the question.  *Of course* you understand what's being asked.  The problem is that no one else could.

> My point being the question *can* and *would* be answered in it's original form if hadn't been closed shortly.

That's an invalid argument, since it apparently "*can* and *would* be answered" only by you.

Since the question (and now the answer) are filled with subjective language and no real question is evident, I've closed the question again.

The answer to your meta question is not to reopen a bad question.  You should have just improved the original question (first thing Cody suggested in the comments) so that it would be understandable and useful to others.

Comment: As I have mentioned in my comments to Lance's answer, the question outlines a *rare* but indeed very *real* situation and due to that rarity it might be confusing and misleading to many (read most). 
The question clearly states the problem to the "right" eyes. You are not among right people, exactly because you can't understand it. Symptoms are not *familiar* to you. you get confused, you call it a rant. The fact that I try to find the solution to my own problem doesn't make the question "vague" and "rant"

Comment: @ashy: Were your answers to this post not helpful to you?: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100661/my-question-is-closed-due-to-being-subjective-and-rant-what-are-my-options

Comment: @Wesely Indeed helpful but perhaps you would kindly elaborate?

Comment: @ashy: You're asking the community what they think, yet you seem to not be taking any of it into consideration - but rather opposing it. To me, it appears you are looking for sympathy, and not truly trying to learn what you can do to improve the community, or your posts. In short, your mouth seems to be open but not your ears.

Comment: @ashy_32bit: There are literally hundreds of thousands of questions on Stack Overflow where I'm not a domain expert.  That has nothing to do with the closure of your question.  When you refer to a piece of software as "dumb", "unintelligent", and "buggy", that's a rant no matter what the domain.

Comment: @Wesley I *seem* not taking any of *your* suggestions (or the likes)  into consideration, not the community. People can disagree with you as they do with me. You say "do this to improve" it, I think it could be seen very good the way it is and I present reasons just like you do. We try to reach somewhere. We may or we may not.

Comment: @ashy: I haven't offered any suggestions yet, but I will now: When you ask a question on meta and get responses that all point in the same direction, you should probably listen to them and try to learn something, otherwise - what was the point of asking in the first place? You *still* have yet to make any effort to improve the question, it is still in the same state as it was when you opened this post. You have been given good advice by the community, and done nothing with it. I think you may just enjoy ranting and blowing off steam, try to turn that energy into something productive.

Comment: You actually did make a good number of assertions and suggested thereof implicitly. Perhaps you don't see it like that. I'm feeling productive the way I do, if you feel your time is wasted, simply do what you should as a caring member and leave it to others to deal with the situation.
By the way, I see quite few members of the community thinking my question was good the way it was. They showed it by helping me re-opening it. I didn't missed the fact that it got closed again (apparently by one person) yet did you miss it getting re-opened in the middle?

Comment: @Bill I understand what you mean yet please look at it this way
 - My engine sounds like a sewing machine and it runs like a dying old man. Also when I press the clutch, it rocks forwards and backwards.
[machinist response] 
 - The oil pump it malfunctioning. It's rare but it happens.
[someone else's response]
 - What? You are ranting about your car. Why don't you * * and instead do * * * .
  Who is really ranting here :) ?

Comment: @ashy_32bit: Great example.  There are 100 different things that could be causing that.  Just because you spend four days diagnosing which one thing was actually causing it doesn't validate your description in any way.  No one else could have told you what was wrong from the description alone.

Comment: @ashy: The situation is resolved now (you've posted your answer), and as I said - I personally didn't think your question was that bad. I'm just trying to help you understand why you are getting negative responses, and why your question was closed, to help you avoid it in the future. I sincerely wish you luck and hope this discussion has been valuable to you.

Comment: @ashy_32bit: There is a constructive way to ask questions, and a non-constructive "rant"-ish way of asking questions. If you honestly don't know the difference, than you are going to see a lot more of your questions getting closed. I'm not sure how else to explain it. Bill and others have already pointed out specific words you've used that make the question appear more like a rant in our eyes than a serious question. It should be trivial for a programmer to "refactor" the question not to use those words and express the same meaning in a different way, if there is in fact a real question there.

Comment: @Wesley Thanks for seeing the value in my question. It's clear I'm faced with (mainly but not entirely) negative responses. I do not consider it a failure that should be avoided at all costs or an indication that something is wrong.
Actually I praise the fact that people can openly discuss their points. To me it's natural, it happens. It should happen. It's a sing of progress. Yet people may feel bored ... if so, just leave it! I would leave it myself the moment I feel I have to. For now, I still want to stay (unless you got a dictator under the hood ;) )

Comment: @Bill Thanks; yet I must disagree. There are not really 100 different things that can cause that. It's *your assumption* that there are, because you are not familiar with it. There is nothing wrong with that. You didn't know the answer! neither did I! perhaps no-one did at the time! It's a relatively new software after all, only recently being spotted by the major public. So far so good.
Yet you interpret it in the context of *your* assumptions about the problem. Thats where things seem to get bad in your (most) eyes.
if(post_conatains($post,nosays)) close_post($post,RANT);

Comment: @ashy_32bit: I don't know how I can put it any more plainly than I already have.  When you describe the software as "dumb" and "buggy" you're being subjective.  You're obviously not really interested in getting the question reopened or you would just remove the subjective language and ask a real question.  I'm done arguing with you.

Comment: @Cody Refactoring the question would kill the point. The point being: one should not machine-likely preg_match() a text against some predefined words and then decide about what it means. I gave specific examples with details as to what happens and what I expect. I gave details about the hosting environment. I even asked if anyone else is seeing this and I finally gave the *correct* answer along with some useful information I acquired in research. The preg_match words are ways to convey the experience as diagnostics means not complaints (pay attention to the *other* parts of the question).

Comment: @Bill I don't know how it make it clear that I understand the preg_match() thing, I'm not "correcting" it deliberately so it can remain in it's original form for the reference. Thanks for your participations though.

Answer (score -3):

Questions sometimes get closed by those unsympathetic to those who have the problem.  They should have left time for an answer, then closed after that as `too localized`.

*I've had questions closed on me because it didn't relate to other's programming problems, though it sure related to mine.*

Comment: Maybe that's why *some* people cast close votes. But that's not why *five* people cast close votes. And this question wasn't closed as "too localized", it was closed as "not a real question", which to me implies that the question was not understandable or problematic on some other level. As usual, your extreme pessimism is puzzling to me.

Comment: @cody, it's puzzling to me why you call it _pessimism_, I call it analysis.  I've been around here a few years, and seen many of these type of things happen, including to myself.  And as you know, __all voting tends to cascade__.

Comment: It's true that seeing `close(1)` usually attracts the other close votes, sometimes incorrectly and without thinking or reading the question, but this post did have the tone of an unconstructive rant.

Comment: @Cody: I agree with Lance here. Some times people vote to close because they personally don't understand the problem and the inability to answer the question. I have come across a question where some one posted the comment `What's the question here?` but I could understand OP's problem and also provide a solution to OP's issue. As Lance said, voting does tend to cascade.

Comment: I think it has to do with empathy/sympathy; because I've been in these 'new user' situations before, I can always empathize with them.  I've been in their shoes.

Comment: I just haven't seen this on the main site (Meta is likely different and irrelevant here). When people vote to close questions as NARQ, it's never been because they can't empathize with the user's problem or because they don't know the answer. I *certainly* don't vote to close questions for that reason, and I just haven't seen any anecdotal evidence of others doing that. Even if 1 person does it, how do we get to 5 votes? This seems a lot like the widespread "fact" of sympathy upvotes. The data just doesn't support that hypothesis, as much as many people seem to be adamant about its truth.

Comment: @Cody, I totally agree that one might make a mistake but not all. But is it really sound to put so much confidence in the judgment of only 5 people in such a large community as SO?
I may mention, as a counter-argument, that PO earned the re-open votes in relatively no-time. Following your logic it shows that original moderators was wrong as enough people disagree with them.

Comment: @ashy_32bit: Yeah, I think 5 people is still a reasonable number. You can't compare it to the entire base of SO users, but rather to the number of people who actually look at each question. Check the page view counter in the right sidebar. And arguing that it got quickly re-opened is kind of cheating. :-) Posting a question on Meta has a *huge* magnifying effect. Either the question you bring to our attention will get re-opened, or it'll get *massively* downvoted and possibly even deleted. It's a gamble, but it *does* work and that's what we're all here for.

Comment: It got closed again anyway, which kind of dampens the "look how fast it was reopened" argument

Comment: @Weseley I don't see the rant and nonconstructive parts. Perhaps the question outlines a relatively rare situation but the symptoms are described quite clearly with enough data for the right people to give answers. Right people would be those who has actually came across the situation and got it resolved. 
How exactly you would propose the question should have been asked to avoid being perceived as rant by some, considering the PO's right to use his own preferred style of composure?

Comment: @ashy_32bit: What does "PO" stand for?

Comment: @ashy: Mainly the first paragraph, it sounds more like a complaint than informative, which sets the overall tone of the post ("code completion looks rather dump and unintelligent to me, to the the point of being useless"). Personally, I would not have closed it, and I think your answer is useful, but I can definitely see how others could view it in a negative way. (Side note: The abbreviation is "OP" which means "original poster")

Comment: @Bill: It means "pissed off" :)

Comment: @Michael It actually states there is a fair chance for both sides to express their opinions. It doesn't dampen anything unless you insist upon making such a thing out of it. I respect those who think it should be closed and I hope to see they respect me back. I am simply trying to state my opposition. I think the key here is the rarity of the situation.

Comment: @Bill I meant OP, it's called a typo. You know, they happen sometimes :) You really didn't get it or perhaps you are just kidding?

Comment: @Weslet nice one :)

Comment: @ashy Well, usually people don't refer to "the OP" when they're talking about themselves

Comment: @ashy_32bit: I really didn't get it.  You used it twice, plus you *are* the OP.

Comment: @Bill, Michael Because I'm a hypocrite ;)

Comment: Man, this *really* should be moved to chat. These comments are easily ten times as long as the answer they're attached to.

Answer (score -5):

Comments put aside, I think the correct answer would be:

You need a certain number (apparently 5) of re-open votes then you can answer the question.

> I've cast the first reopen vote, you need 4 more. – Lance

Comment: In general, you are more likely to get reopen votes if the question is improved to meet the guidelines. Your question in its current form very closely resembles a complaint about software (From the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) it is a rant disguised as a question: “______ sucks, am I right?”), which is close-fodder for those who don't care to read between the lines and see the actual question (if there is one). It's really a matter of semantics in some cases, that's why you've been urged to improve the question by some, and why others already do see it as a legit question.