# Where is the appropriate place to ask subjective questions?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My question is closed due to being “subjective” and “rant” , what are my options?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100661/my-question-is-closed-due-to-being-subjective-and-rant-what-are-my-options)

I often would like to get the opinions of other developers, as the SO structure is great even for subjective Q&A.  However, I think this may be prohibited?  Is there a correct way to ask such a question?

Answer (score 9):

Programmers.StackEx—*just kidding*.

No but seriously, there's no place in the Stack Exchange network to ask open-ended, subjective questions.  Those questions are fundamentally off topic everywhere, though some communities may [bend that rule](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124911/individual-community-preferences-vs-se-network-policy-who-wins) slightly more than others.

---

I've never really been there, but you could *try* asking your question on [Quora](http://www.quora.com/)

Comment: +1 for the first line. Reddit and Yahoo Answers are also good places to go.

Comment: @Cody - I thought Reddit was just for sharing news articles.  Or is that digg?  Gah, I'm so uncool.

Comment: You mean to imply there might be *rules* on Reddit? Wow, I didn't know. Don't feel bad; I'm pretty uncool, too.